# react-virtualized Masonry server rendered output doesn't match client rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-virtualized, next.js

I'm trying to build a layout which is very similar to Pinterest with react-virtualized Masonry, WindowScroller, and AutoSizer components. In fact, it's not much different from [the sample given on their official website](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Masonry). Also, I'm using nextjs and prefer to enable server-side rendering for this layout.

For generating grid items in the server-side, as per to the react-virtualized documentation, I set some random values to WindowScroller's `serverHeight` and `serverWidth` props as well as AutoSizer's `defaultHeight` and `defaultWidth` props. However, since those values are different from the actual browser width and height, server and client generate a different number of grid items in the initial rendering. This makes a mismatch between server-generated and client-generated HTML markups and React gives following warning.

`Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>.`

How can I get rid of this warning by making server and client generate the same number of grid items in the initial rendering or instructing React to simply makes the necessary changes required to match server-generated markup to client-generated one?